# Existence of a probability measure defined on balls

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$  and  $X_n \sim N(0, \sigma_n^2)$ be independent.
We have  $d_X (m, n)= R(m,n)= \sqrt {\sigma_m^2 + \sigma_n^2 }$ and  $\sigma_n^2$ decreases to 0. I want to define a  majorizing measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{N}$. 
so that

$\hspace{3cm} \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \int_{0}^{D} \sqrt{\log{(\mu(B(n,\epsilon))^{-1})}} du <\infty$

Where  $\epsilon >0$ and $ D= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sigma_n < \infty$.

Let $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ be a separable metric or pseudo–metric space with the topology induced by $d$. We use $B(n, \epsilon)$ to denote a closed ball of radius $\epsilon$ in
$\mathbb{N}$ centered at $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I define a probability measure $\mu$ in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You need to be more precise, because there are an infinity of different probabilities. What properties do you need ?

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. I have edited my question.

Comment: What is $B(n,\epsilon)$? You will have to clarify your terminology and notations.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected it.